# Multiplying varchar by negative 1 gives a 0 until '.05'

Tags: sql, sql-server

Came across an odd thing when trying to convert a decimal that is a varchar into a negative.

**Line 1**

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(decimal(3,2),'0.01')*-1 as Line1 --correct way
```

> | Line1 |
> | --- |
> | -0.01 |

Shows the correct way, nothing weird there, as expected

**Line 2**

```sql
SELECT '0.01'*-1.0 as Line2 --original problem
```

> | Line2 |
> | --- |
> | 0.00 |

I thought implicit conversion was going to be lucky enough here to just take care of the precedence and give me the -.01 that I was looking for.  It instead returns 0.00.

**Line 3**

```sql
SELECT '0.1'*-1.0 as Line3 --moving decimal
```

> | Line3 |
> | --- |
> | -0.10 |

I wondered what moving the decimal place would do.  That returns what I would have expected line 2 to return, just with .01 instead of .1.
 
**Line 4/5/6**

```sql
SELECT '0.0499999999999999999'*-1.0 as Line4 --what is the limit?
SELECT '0.05'*-1.0 as Line5 --what is the limit (apparently .05)?
SELECT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY('0.05'*-1.0, 'basetype') as Line,SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY('0.05'*-1.0, 'precision') as [6],SQL_VARIANT_Property('0.05'*-1.0, 'scale') as [ ] --what's the type
```

> | Line4 |
> | --- |
> | 0.00 |

> | Line5 |
> | --- |
> | -0.10 |

> | Line | 6 |  |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | numeric | 5 | 2 |

I then started to go down the path of "what is the final value needed before it changes".  I incremented the '.01' until I got something, which happened to be '.05'.  At this point, it returns -.1.  Using `SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY` on that result returns a numeric(5,2) data type. I thought maybe it was a rounding thing, decided to go back just the tiniest bit. Still 0 (line 4) so the rounding thought seems to be correct.

**Line 7**

```sql
SELECT '0.09'*-1.0 as Line7 --what is the limit (apparently .05)?
```

> | Line7 |
> | --- |
> | -0.10 |

Repeat experiment of Line 4, just with a slightly larger number. Thought I might get something else.

**Line 8**

```sql
SELECT '0.01'*-1.00 as Line8 --works but with extra decimals in output
```

> | Line8 |
> | --- |
> | -0.0100 |

For some reason, adding another 0 to the end of the -1.0 ends up with a numeric(7,4) instead, while also converting the varchar to the negative (albeit with extra unwanted scale).  Further adding a 0 to the -1.0 increases the precision and scale by 2 each i.e. -1.000 gives numeric(9,6), -1.0000 gives numeric(11,8), etc.

What is the behavior behind this?  Why would adding 2 zeroes get me the expected value when 1 does not, even though both are decimals?

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: The "real* question is why are you using a `varchar` to represent a numerical value; that's the *real* problem.

Comment: If you display execution plans, you will see in the Compute Scalars what sql converts your values to in the various SELECTs.

Comment: Or, if you actually posted the code as `text`, we could copy and paste that code and explain the behaviour.

Comment: @siggemannen tried that before posting, nothing happens when you have Include Actual Execution Plan enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: Don't use `varchar`s to represent numerical values, and if you are be **explicit** with the target data type. Better yet, *fix* the problem at the root.

---

All these results as expected. For Line 2 you implicitly cast `'0.01'` to a `decimal(2,1)`, which is `0.0`, so you get `0.00` after the multiplication in the resulting `decimal(5,2)`:

```sql
SELECT '0.01'*-1.0 as Line2,
       CAST('0.01' AS decimal(2,1))*-1.0,
       0.0*-1.0
```

For line 3 the logic is identical, apart from you have `'0.1'`, so precision isn't lost.

Again, the same for Lines 4-7; you're casting to a `decimal(2,1)`, and that value is rounded to, 0.04999~ is closer to 0 than 0.1, while 0.05 is closer to 0.1; this is basic rounding.

Line 8, you implicitly cast to a `decimal(3,2)` and so you get `0.01` and thus a different result.

All of this would be avoided if you were explicit with your casting/converting and specified the precision you need:

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(decimal(3,2),'0.01')*-1.0;
```

But really you shouldn't be using a string based data type for numerical data in the first place; use the correct data type to start with. Here you should just be typing `0.01` rather than `'0.01'`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on the decimal(2,1), that is where my confusion was coming from.  Definitely aware of storing the value in the proper type, this was more an exploration of why this is happening.